# Class getting Undefined by other header?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

this is a really awkward moment: I never thought anything like this can happen.

the error I receive is the following:

```
AskGUISupport.cpp(40): error C2039: 'RoomStd' : is not a member of 'MW'
```

The includes contain the following lines:

```
#include "ObjectCompareModal.h"
#include "RoomStd.h"

//...

t[RT_ROOM] = std::pair<DisplaySubMap_Ty, MemberFn> (tmp,
        &AskGUIFn::ExecuteFn<MW::RoomStd>);
```

Where t is simply a map (not really important).

If I comment out the very first include it DOES work - then it correctly recognizes the class "RoomStd" (defined in the `RoomStd.h` header). However when `ObjectCompareModal.h` header is included the program just pops this error.

The headers are almost the same:

**ObjectCompareModal.h**:

```
namespace MW {
    class GenStd : public TreeCompareDialog {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        GenStd() : TreeCompareDialog() 
        {
            ui.setupUi(this);
            DuplicateButtonBox = ui.ChoiceButtons;
            QObject::connect(ui.ChoiceButtons, SIGNAL(clicked(QAbstractButton*)), this, SLOT(OnClick(QAbstractButton*)));
        }
        GenStd(const pTree* o, const pTree* n) : TreeCompareDialog(o, n)
        {
            ui.setupUi(this);
            DuplicateButtonBox = ui.ChoiceButtons;
            QObject::connect(ui.ChoiceButtons, SIGNAL(clicked(QAbstractButton*)), this, SLOT(OnClick(QAbstractButton*)));
        }
        Ui::Form ui;
    };
}
```

**RoomStd.h**

```
namespace MW {
    class RoomStd : public TreeCompareDialog {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        RoomStd() : TreeCompareDialog() 
        {
            ui.setupUi(this);
            DuplicateButtonBox = ui.ChoiceButtons;
            QObject::connect(ui.ChoiceButtons, SIGNAL(clicked(QAbstractButton*)), this, SLOT(OnClick(QAbstractButton*)));
        }
        RoomStd(const pTree* o, const pTree* n) : TreeCompareDialog(o, n)
        {
            ui.setupUi(this);
            DuplicateButtonBox = ui.ChoiceButtons;
            QObject::connect(ui.ChoiceButtons, SIGNAL(clicked(QAbstractButton*)), this, SLOT(OnClick(QAbstractButton*)));
        }
        Ui::Form ui;
    };
}
```

WHAT is causing this? It really startles me how a similar class "destroys" another class for the compiler?

EDIT: when I swap the includes around (so first roomstd is included, the same problem occurs, but then the compiler complains about GenStd not being a member of namespace MW).

Comment: Didn't you forget the enclosing '}' in the first header?

Comment: Copy mistake with the closeing of namespace

Comment: Did you try to change the order of your #include's ?

Comment: @kids_fox Just did - see my edit: the "same" problem happens, but about GenStd instead of RoomStd this time.

Comment: Are those complete and precise copies of the header files? Are there no comments, no include guards?

Comment: Does not look like you have any include guards, also is it possible that you accidentally included these files elsewhere inside of another namespace?

Comment: @paul23, well, if i understand correctly these headers should be processed with a 3rd party precompiler. You may turn on the option to generate the asm+ code listing in Properties-> C/C++ ->Output files page. Thus you may inspect the actual code you are compiling. It may help you to get an idea on what happens

Comment: @rob OMG *bashes head-keyboard few times*. That was it - I used to use pragma once. But just last week started to use include guards to provide guaranteed cross compatibility. But the headers are (now) just copy-pastes of each other. - Thus with wrong inclusion guards (both TREECOMPAREMODAL_H as keyword). Sorry everyone for the annoyance